# Add ProcessorResponse property to SwagPaypal plugin

Tags: shopware6

I need to track the `ProcessorResponse` property in the `Capture` node of the Paypal REST Api response.
Since SwagPaypal does not map it in `SwagPayPal/src/RestApi/V2/Api/Order/PurchaseUnit/Payments/Capture.php` I tried to create a plugin with the same namespace (`Swag\PayPal\RestApi\V2\Api\Order\PurchaseUnit\Payments`) extending Capture class.

However in the `assign` method of `SwagPayPal/src/RestApi/PayPalApiStruct.php` my property is not found.

Am I doing something not possible?

Should I open a PR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an existing namespace is no way of extending another class/service and in fact should be actively avoided.

There's the service `Swag\PayPal\RestApi\V2\Resource\CaptureResource` which you could replace with your own service using a [compiler pass](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/rate-limiter/add-rate-limiter-to-api-route#adding-compiler-pass-to-the-container).

```php
class CaptureResourceCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $container->getDefinition(CaptureResource::class)->setClass(MyCustomCaptureResource::class);
    }
}
```

In the replaced service return an instance of your extension of `Capture` instead.

```php
class MyCustomCaptureResource extends CaptureResource
{
    private PayPalClientFactoryInterface $payPalClientFactory;

    public function __construct(PayPalClientFactoryInterface $payPalClientFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct($payPalClientFactory);
        
        $this->payPalClientFactory = $payPalClientFactory;
    }

    public function get(string $captureId, string $salesChannelId): Capture
    {
        $response = $this->payPalClientFactory->getPayPalClient($salesChannelId)->sendGetRequest(
            \sprintf('%s/%s', RequestUriV2::CAPTURES_RESOURCE, $captureId)
        );

        return (new MyCustomCapture())->assign($response);
    }
}
```

```php
class MyCustomCapture extends Capture
{
    protected $processorResponse = null;

    public function getProcessorResponse()
    {
        return $this->processorResponse;
    }

    public function setProcessorResponse($processorResponse): void
    {
        $this->processorResponse = $processorResponse;
    }
}
```

I omitted the type hints in the `Capture` extension since I don't know the type of `ProcessorResponse`. You should add them if you know the type.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I tried also to use the 'Swag\PayPal\RestApi\V2\Resource\OrderResource' but got stuck extending 'Swag\PayPal\RestApi\V2\Api\Order\PurchaseUnit' 'Payments' field

this attempt was to avoid calling PayPal Api two times ('v2/checkout/orders') and then 'v2/payments/captures'